# Shopify Liquid Show Button If Variant Not Available

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm trying to show a button that says "Email me when Available" if a product variant is not available. I'm trying to use the same logic as the Debut Theme does to have the button say "add to cart" or "sold out".

```
<div class="product-form__item product-form__item--submit{% if section.settings.enable_payment_button %} product-form__item--payment-button{% endif %}{% if product.has_only_default_variant %} product-form__item--no-variants{% endif %}">
            <button type="submit" name="add" {% unless current_variant.available %}disabled="disabled"{% endunless %} class="btn product-form__cart-submit{% if section.settings.enable_payment_button %} btn--secondary-accent{% endif %}" data-add-to-cart>
              <span data-add-to-cart-text>
                {% unless current_variant.available %}
                  {{ 'products.product.sold_out' | t }}
                {% else %}
                  {{ 'products.product.add_to_cart' | t }}
                {% endunless %}
              </span>
            </button>


            {% unless current_variant.available %}
                <button class="btn BIS_trigger" data-product-data='{{ product | json | escape }}'>
                  Email When Available
               </button>
            {% endunless %}

          </div>
```

What I can't understand is why the "unless current_variant.available" logic works in the button above, but not in part.

Our "not available" variants are set to have Shopify track inventory and the available inventory at zero. We set the available variants to not tracking inventory.

How can I make this work?

Comment: It may be a dumb question but I have to ask it. Are you changing the variants and expecting the `Email When Available` to show you reach a variant that is not available?

Comment: Yes... we have 1 product in 4 variants. 2 are in stock and 2 won't be available for a few weeks.

Comment: Well the issue is clear then. The liquid is templating language that loads before any DOM elements. So when you change the variant the liquid code isn't aware of any changes since it was finished with the rendering. Or to say it in more simple terms if you buy a cow milk and change the label to say goat milk it will still be cow milk. ;) You must use javascript in order to update when to show the button and remove the unless altogether.

Comment: @drip yes that all makes sense... maybe I can leverage existing javascript on the page:

Comment: {%- for variant in product.variants -%}
      {
        "@type" : "Offer",
        {%- if variant.sku != blank -%}
          "sku": {{ variant.sku | json }},
        {%- endif -%}
        "availability" : "http://schema.org/{% if product.available %}InStock{% else %}OutOfStock{% endif %}",
        "price" : {{ variant.price | divided_by: 100.00 | json }},
        "priceCurrency" : {{ cart.currency.iso_code | json }},
        "url" : {{ shop.url | append: variant.url | json }}
      }{% unless forloop.last %},{% endunless %}
    {%- endfor -%}